# Connect Signal and Slots in QT

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Is it possible to connect a signal of class A to its own slot

Example as `connect(objecta1, Signala1,objecta1,slota1)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a class can react to its own signals. Be careful to not emit the signal from the triggered slots though.

Comment: is it illegal to emit a signal from a triggered slot?

Comment: It is absolutelly not illegal to emit a signal from a triggered slot. Sometimes it's useful to emit another signal (with different parameters for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very simple for example a QTimer:

```
myClass::myClass(QObject * parent):QObject(parent) {
    timer = new QTimer();
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(myClassTimeout() ));
    timer->start(1000);
}
```

Then you have

```
void myClass::myClassTimeout() { 
//...
}
```